# Workflow to re-topologise CAD converted model meshes to quad topology

Tags: mesh, topology

I am receiving DWF CAD files from our design team to convert into renderable models for our website.

I use the [PolyTrans|CAD+DCC Translation System](https://www.okino.com/conv/conv.htm) to convert these into files that Blender can accept. Namely **.FBX** or **.OBJ**. Despite my best efforts the Okino converter pretty much always outputs the same type of mesh, which is a mixture of quads, tris, and some other interpretation of the CAD model. It looks like this:

[image: Resulting Mesh]

I have been looking around for retopologising tools to do this automatically and so far these are the main issues I have run into:

- **Blender Remesh Modifier**: It does create an evenly spaced quad mesh but it requires millions of verticies to recreate the piece accurately with hard edges represented correctly. It also struggles with the CAD created rounded edges, so Remeshing and then feeding into another retopo tool seems excessive.
- [**Instant-Meshes Tool**](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes): Great tool, doesn't work well when you need to create an output mesh that has (roughly) equally spaced quads when the initial mesh has fewer verticies than the final one. It just gets confused by the flow of the mesh as it tries to follow the output one from the CAD converter.

I am aware there is the [Exoside Quad Remesher](https://exoside.com/quadremesher/) tool which is paid, but I haven't tried it yet as I imagine its algorithm would end up having the same issues as the Instant-Remesher Tool. Has anyone used it with this type of topology that could comment?

Does anyone know of a more efficient/established workflow to convert the types of meshes shown above into quad topology that is somewhat automated?

**NOTE**: A completely even quad topology is not necessary, dynamic topology to save on model size is the most welcome outcome.

Comment: Exoside Quad Remesher produces better results than Instant-Meshes based on my experience. There's a free 30 day trial, give it a go. You may also wish to look into Moi. It's exporter is interactive and produces superior results that necessitate less clean up work.